# How to reply to recruiter that did not read my resume on LinkedIn

Tags: resume, job-search, recruitment

A recruiter working for a big company contacted me on LinkedIn and asked whether I am interested in a certain position that requires expert level knowledge in A. The thing is that A is mentioned on my LinkedIn profile with a) very little experience b) very long time ago - since then I was doing totally different things.

There is clearly no match for the current offer but I would not mind to hear about other relevant opportunities. 
How should I respond?

Comment: Ask the recruiter if they have any relevant positions for your current experience, if they don't then tell them to notify you in the case something pops up

Comment: I would either 1) not respond at all if the company does not interest me, or 2) respond by telling them the required skill is something I haven't worked with in a while but I would be open to hear about other relevant opportunities.

Comment: Doesn't this apply to most recruiters?

Comment: That makes more sense. You may also want to formulate a better question than "*How should I respond?*". We don't typically cover questions that tell you what you should do. If you think this means the recruiter isn't worth working with you should simply ignore him. If you think it might still be useful to have him pass future, more relevant, job openings then you should. Perhaps your actual question is more: "*Is it worth working with a recruiter who contacted me about a job I'm not qualified for?*"?

Comment: What, do you owe him money? Quite frankly you can reply however you like, including, NOT AT ALL. If the recruiter is wasting your time with an unsolicited and worthless message, you should not waste anymore time with that recruiter. That includes spending time asking strangers how to deal with him in a civil manner.

Comment: From what I understand, pretty much anyone can buy a linkedin premium account and call themself a recruiter.  To find matches, they can do a simple search for the skill they're looking for and mass-message everyone who pops up.  I don't think professional recruiters use this spray and pray tactic so chances are, it's not worth your time to respond. I can almost guarantee that you won't hear from them ever again.

Comment: I think everyone here is overthinking this... *recruiters don't read CVs for cold calls anymore*. They have computer scanning software that searches various popular Resume sites for keyword values and pulls back a list of hits. If you don't want recruiters making useless cold calls to you then take technology A off of your CV. Otherwise, this is likely going to happen as often as some company needs that particular skill.

Comment: If you had very little experience with A long time ago, maybe you could have more experience with that now, just didn't bother to include that? There are people (including recruiters) who don't include everything on their LinkedIn and might expect the same from you. So it might be worth to ask if they haven't got a plenty of other options.

Comment: Try to remember you are the commodity. Without you a recruiter has nothing. It follows then that you should ignore all recruiters (don't waste their time or yours) until you're actively searching for a job. At that point, call several of them and make them work for you. The one who does the best job and finds you the job you want gets paid. Simple.

Comment: Honestly I also do not understand recruiters coming from linked.in asking for my CV "to see if I match the profile they need"

Comment: As @DanK has already said, but in another form "Don't spend time on someone, who spent no time on you".

Comment: Definitely take A off your CV. In five or ten years, you might stop getting useless inquiries about it.

Comment: @AffableAmbler "I don't think professional recruiters use this spray and pray tactic" - I would respectfully disagree. I use a unique email address on each resume I send out, so I know I'm not getting responses to my LinkedIn profile when I get direct emails from recruiters who are contacting me about skill sets I haven't used in a decade, or are barely relevant to something I've mentioned on my resume. I have, occasionally, responded with "If you can't be bothered to read my resume, I _don't_ want you representing me in any way!". Sadly, I doubt that ever gets to the boss...

Comment: Most honest recruiter: “hey, I found you on LinkedIn/GitHub/Stackoverflow. This qualifies you for the position I am recruiting for.“

Answer (score 90, accepted):

My personal opinion is that it's not worthwhile to try to work with recruiters who are unable to evaluate my resume against the requirements of an open position.

But if you want to try anyway, and since this is a company recruiter, just reply with something along the lines of:

> "Thank you for your interest, but unfortunately I don't think this
>   position is a match for my skills.  However, I would be interested in
>   other opportunities with your company that are more focused on (insert
>   whatever you're looking for).  Please contact me if you have any open
>   positions of this sort."

Finally, it's good to pare down the skillset listed on your resume to match what you would actually feel comfortable and qualified doing.

Comment: Agree completely. Recruiters are a penny a dozen (I'm from the UK), but GOOD recruiters are like hens teeth. I've personally got three recruiters who I regularly talk to, and refer people I know to. Someone not reading your LinkedIn profile is the sign of a bad recruiter (in my opinion, before anyone gets bent out of shape)

Comment: My only disagreement is that I WOULD NOT REPLY at all.

Comment: @DarkHippo I agree completely, I only have around 2 recruiters whom I keep in contact with. I've had a recruiter approach me with a _fantastic_ job offer before via LinkedIn, I might've gone for it if it wasn't for the fact it was the job I left 3 months ago...

Comment: @Aron +1 I would never reply to a recruiter who didn't bother doing basic research on my profile. Not worth my time.

Comment: @George funny you should say that. I had the exact same thing happen to me the other week. It was only after telling them that they checked my Linked In profile...

Comment: I'd add to make sure the person really is a recruiter for the company. I often receive LinkedIn requests from people claiming to be a recruiter at a large company, but in reality they work for a recruiting firm and are hoping to pass your info onto the company. This is a common practice (some would say scam). I would not do business with such a recruiter ever.

Comment: Headhunters are a dime a dozen (and in my experience usually don't add any value to the process) but company-internal recruiters are not. Depending on the size of the company that recruiter may be the only one, so if you ever want to work there, don't be rude. But that said every recruiter is surely used to not getting responses.

Answer (score 21):

I also find this a regular problem, however I only consider it game over if the requirement is clearly unrelated to anything I have specified as an experience or skill I possess.

Often, there are skills I have used in a previous job but I am still interested in going back to them in the future.

Personally, I would say to this recruiter
"Thank you for your proposition. This role sounds very interesting but I notice it focuses on skill A which I have not used in a professional environment since 2011. I am especially interested in hearing from you about roles where I can utilize skills B, C and D"

A final point to consider is that the skill and attitude of recruiters can vary wildly, even within a company. Burning a bridge with this person could affect relationships with their colleagues who may be far more helpful.

Comment: Whoever downvoted could you please explain what part of my answer you disagree with

Comment: The first clause is spot on, and a good answer.  +1 from me.  There are plenty of cranky people on this site that down vote good answers.

Answer (score 9):

Did you make sure that expert knowledge in A is really necessary?

It might be that they would like to get an expert, tried to find one for a while, and gradually reduced the requirements (internally - they will still ask for an expert officially) until even someone with at least a bit of experience is acceptable for the job.

Sometimes you just don't find what you want, so you have to take what you can get. Just make sure that they know that your expertise in A is limited. If they still accept, fine.

Comment: Right. Not to mention that some companies overstate "requirements" so you feel "lucky" to be qualified at all, placing the company in a more favorable position during any bargaining. I was taught in college: "requirements" lie. They're not actually required. Huge amounts of people are getting successfully hired, despite not matching every listed requirement. @Asahi: Do not let that dissuade you. (Another possibility: it could also be that the LinkedIn posting you saw might be for a second position.) In short, definitely don't let this stop you. Don't even let it lower your confidence too much.

Comment: I'd also add that skills can be learned (faster if you already have some experience with the topic). If a company is not in rush for a specific position then your knowledge is just an investment they do for your future as employee. I'm a programmer, imagine that a company contacts me for a position where language X is required. I actually know little or nothing about X but my skills and my experience make me a good fit. I can learn X (probably starting even before I start working there). Not all companies (especially smaller ones) act this way but it's a possibility.

Answer (score 7):

Either this is a very incapable recruiter, or there are *no other relevant opportunities for you at that company*. You're better off searching that company's website for opportunities that might be a better match for you, if they exist at all.

I can imagine that the recruiter received an assignment to look for people proficient in a certain Skill A. He/she stumbled on your profile on LinkedIn, and (assuming he/she is capable) didn't find any other matches among your skills, and contacts you in the off chance that you're actually interested in a career 'switch' to a job involving Skill A.

Answer (score 7):

A vast majority of "cold calls" made by recruiters are just bots / scrapers. They scan your profile or resume for keywords and then email you with a generic canned message. That is why they cannot / do not differentiate between "a little experience" and "a lot," it's almost always just a positive hit on the keyword match.

So the appropriate response is to just delete the message if you are not interested.

If you are interested, then reach out to them and they will discuss your experience and capabilities at that point and tell you if they think you are a good fit or not. Most jobs have flexibility (within reason) with regard to the requirements. You won't know unless you ask.

Even if the recruiter did read your profile and write you a message, he either made a mistake or misread. I think the rules still apply for a cold call... if you're interested you reply, if not ignore.

> There is clearly no match for the current offer but I would not mind to hear about other relevant opportunities.

Then this sounds like the perfect thing to mention in your reply.